# Unity3D friends scoreboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, unity-game-engine

I need to add a scoreboard to my game using user's facebook friends list.
I've tried using app42 from shephertz framework to do that but I'm not able to get it working. (Their docs needs some improvements).

Could it be a good idea creating a custom DB with rails with a single table with the following schema? BestScore(facebook_id as PK, score)
Then when I need to get friends' score I would post their ids, received from a Facebook sdk api call, to an endpoint which searches a score foreach given user and returns a leaderboard. The complexity of the whole thing should be O(nFriends * log(dbEntries)).

Better ideas?

Comment: hey massimo, the only realistic way to do this is with the Prime31 plugin.  (it's a shame to have to pay a few dollars but there's just no other way.)  BTW it is just ridiculously difficult working with the FB system - hope it goes OK for you!

Comment: "a custom DB with ..." you would never do that in a million years dude, just use back4appm, or firebase, or similar